# How to extract certificate from p7b file in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, certificate

In command line I can successfully extract all 3 certificates from my p7b file:

```
openssl pkcs7 -in mscep.p7b -inform der -print_certs -outform PEM -out certfile.pem
```

Is there a way to do it also in PHP? I tried to search around , but only openssl_pkcs7_.... functions dealt with encryption and decryption.

Basically I need to extract CA root certificate from the chain I get back from MSCEP

Comment: Do you have to use a p7b format or can you convert it before you need to read it in PHP?

Comment: I query it from ...mscep.dll?operation=GetCACert... in my PHP code. As CA cert doesn't change very often, I decided to extract it beforehand and store it in separate file. But it would be nice to do it in realtime if possible